# Не видны пользовательские модули при запуске тестов через терминал

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pytest

При выполнении кода через терминал PyCharm вот такая ошибка:

> MoudleNotFoundError: No module named 'SauceBasePage'

[image: снимок экрана со стрелками]

При этом модуль есть, и если запускать файл по кнопке интерфейса, то код отрабатывает. В чем причина ошибки импорта, как можно исправить?

Comment: пакеты и модули для импорта ищутся в первую очередь в текущем каталоге, потом учитывается переменная окружения PYTHONPATH, затем остальное содержимое списка sys.path

Comment: Понятно, но как мою ситуацию исправить?

Comment: Пробуйте в тестах импортировать через имя пакета: `from basic_code.SauceBasePage import *`, и pytest запускать из папки Final_Project через `pytest autotests`.

Comment: Пробовал так- не работает.

Comment: Значит что-то не так делаете (например запускаете из папки тестов, а не из папки проекта). У меня работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmssL.png

Comment: И все же тут другое. Когда я указал from `basic_code.SauceBasePage import *`, `basic_code` подчеркнулось красным c нотификацией Unresolved reference

Comment: Это предупреждение IDE, на работоспособность это никак не влияет.

Comment: Прогнал еще раз. Действительно, вы правы. Но вот интересно: почему нотификации эти появляются?

Comment: Попробуйте на Final_Project слева в дереве нажать правой кнопкой, Mark directory as -> Sources root

Comment: PyCharm ищет импортируемые модули/пакеты в том числе в папках, отмеченных как Sources root. Но pytest об отметках в PyCharm ничего не знает, для него корень - текущая папка, откуда он запущен. Поэтому нужно и pytest запускать из First_Project, и в PyCharm отметить папку First_Project как Sources root.